# Is it possible to count the number of php code lines parsed to complete a request?

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP website which uses Autoload feature to limit number of included files. Is there a way for php engine to count the number of source code lines (and files) it parsed to complete each request? That way it would be easier to optimize the structure to limit include files for each request.

Edit: Let's assume that we are not using op-cache or we can even skip (meaning no need to count) all compiled code. Since this is mainly for profiling in dev environment even instrumenting the php code is acceptable.

I see XDebug has built in profiling feature. I never used it before. I will try that and post-back (http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: How would you count content loaded from the op-cache?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your script is contained within one file, why not output the current line number on it's return using a [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)?

```
echo __LINE__;
```

Comment: Whole application is not in a single file. I use autoload to load classes only when it is required. Each class is in a separate file. Idea was to minimize the number of lines to be parsed. Because of the coding standards there can be empty lines in the code as well.

Comment: If you don't want to count empty lines and require auto-loading, I can't see an easy solution.